R progress bar around standard functions
I'm having trouble understanding how to use progress bars, most examples I see are for monitoring progress in loops. I just want to run a kmeans clustering on a large set of data and want to monitor the progress.
I've tried:
library(progressr)
handlers("txtprogressbar")
progressr::with_progress(clustering.kmeans <- kmeans(data, centers = 10, nstart = 20, iter.max = 50))

but I get no progress bar. I'd appreciate if someone could help.

@Friede no, that's not it! With a very large dataset, I still don't get a progress bar while it takes a while for the process to run.

You need to signal the progression to with_progress. That's easy for loops or parallelization, but I don't think it supports what happens inside kmeans(). So, I don't think it's possible.

For progress bar to work within a call of a function it has to be implemented within that function. If it's not, I believe the only option is to take the code of that function and add the progress bar by youself.
Luckily, the kmeans function (in the stats package) seems to have some kind of progress tracing with the trace argument. But it works only for the default algorithm ("Hartigan-Wong"). This argument can be logical or integer (TRUE converted to 1), which indicates different levels of tracing information. Check it out.
